# What is our standard for spelling?

Tags: discussion, editing

I have edited many questions and answers to change spelling. Do we have a standard about how words are to be spelled, that are differently in different parts of the world?

Example: `Color` and `Colour` (and many more I can't think of now.)

I ask because if we allow multiple spellings of a word, then there will be some answers lost in a search.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is completely optional, even for tags, whichever comes first, we usually just go with that. However, I find that more people opt for the American [spelling](http://www.wikiwand.com/en/American_and_British_English_spelling_differences), *color* over the British *colour* and *modeling* over *modelling* etc. If we were to try and uphold a standard, I'd say the former (which is what I see around here anyway based on our demographic).

Also, see [Micro Editing, does everything need to be perfect?](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/q/241/12), these are rather trivial and you shouldn't edit a post just for the difference in spelling.

Comment: I would not edit a post just to change colour, but when already editing a post I should change colour to be color. Is that right?

Comment: @David Rather trivial IMO but should be fine. Again, see the post I linked to, everything doesn't need to be perfect, just understandable.

Comment: the blender code standard is to use American spelling.