# We or I? Should we (or I) edit?

Tags: discussion

I found this question: [Object rotation in game engine](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/50145/object-rotation-in-game-engine?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Should I edit to replace all the "We"s to "I"s for consistency or is it fine that the OP referrers to him/her self as "we"?

Comment: As an aside, the OP could be working in a team so then it would really be "we."

Comment: ^^ Similarly, I think it's common to use "we" in an answer to refer to both the question poster and the answer writer.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Does not matter (at all). This would be a case of [micro editing](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/q/241/2217), and if that is the only thing in the post to fix, you don't even need to edit it.

There are no set standards on what pronoun, or what tense the questions must be written in. If one user uses "me" and "I" but another uses "you" and "we", it does not make any difference. The information is going to be there either way.

Unless you are a grammar professor <strike>we</strike> you are not going to care, you came to BSE to find out about blender.

Unless it really detracts from the question, or there are other things that you need to fix, there is no need to try to make everything perfect.

Comment: Correction: "Unless *one is* a grammar professor..." :-)